# Not sure if web crawlers read my website correctly

Tags: character-encoding, seo, web-crawler

At the W3C Internationalization Checker page, (http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/ ) I got no errors about language issues for my website [fxrehber.com](http://fxrehber.com) but when I check my website for web crawlers at a website like http://tools.seobook.com/general/spider-test/ I get the text like these:

> SPK Lisansl Forex irketlerinin Kar la t rmalar ve Kullan c Yorumlar
>   FXrehber com Forex irketleri kar la t rma ve yorumlar Forex'te g venle
>   i lem yap n T rkiye'de ofisi bulunan

My website is in Turkish, so it should look like this:

> SPK Lisanslı Forex şirketlerinin Karşılaştırmaları ve Kullanıcı Yorumları
>   FXrehber com Forex şirketleri karşılaştırma ve yorumları Forex'te güvenle
>   işlem yapın Türkiye'de ofisi bulunan

I'm not sure if it's normal behaviour and this is a problem for SEO.

Comment: If the question is if the crawlers read your site correctly then the answer is no, they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the tools.seobook.com service useless; it apparently cannot even read UTF-8 data correctly (when in document body – it seems to get the `meta` tag contents OK, making the behavior even more absurd).

If you search for e.g. “SPK Lisanslı Forex şirketlerinin Karşılaştırmaları” in Google, you’ll see your page well placed, with the extract of page content correctly displayed by Google. Ditto when searching with Bing, Yahoo, Yandex.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm more comfortable with it.